# wrong sha1 output in hex

Tags: c, openssl, sha1

My code is supposed to calculate a sha1 hash from a string content and then print it as hex values.

Main function :

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
int main(){
  unsigned char str[] = "A";
  unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // == 20
  SHA1(str, sizeof(str), hash);
  printHash(hash);
  return 0;
}
```

printHash function :

```
void printHash(unsigned char *hash){
  if(hash == NULL){
    printf("HASH NULL\n");
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
    printf("%02X\n", hash[i]);
  }
}
```

The output for the string "A" is :

```
EF420ABFDDBDA7B9EE665D85EF62E4A437554003
```

But when i try on a website like this one : http://www.sha1-online.com/ , i get this result :

```
6dcd4ce23d88e2ee9568ba546c007c63d9131c1b
```

Why is there a difference ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Openssl command line utility gives 6dcd4ce23d88e2ee9568ba546c007c63d9131c1b too, which library you are using to get SHA1 in your code?

Comment: From openssl, i added the include to make it more clear, thank you

Comment: Sidenote: SHA1 is not safe anymore. Many websites and browsers don't accept SHA1 signatures. Use SHA2 with at least 256, better more bits.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid mistake from me, i changed this line :

```
SHA1(str, sizeof(str), hash);
```

to

```
SHA1(str, sizeof(str)-1, hash);
```

and everything works now, thank you

Comment: Or just do `char str[1] = "A";`.